# Regex find and replace but leave code (LETTER-NUMBER-NUMBER) intact

Tags: regex

I have the following tag:

```
<overlay id="B66" x="600">
```

I would like to change the x value but leave everything else intact, but I have other x values for other items which equal 600 so I can't just do a find and replace on x.

I used the following which finds all the  tags:

```
\<overlay id=\"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}\" x=\"600\"
```

However, I would like to leave the ids ("B66") intact while I change the x value.

What should I put as my replace value?

Comment: Which is the programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your regex as:

```
"(<overlay id=\"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}\" x=\")(600)(\")"
```

To split it into three capture groups, where the value of `x` is in the second, the following replacement string should do what you want:

```
"$1New Value$3"
```

Which would generate:

```
<overlay id="B66" x="New Value"
```

**Edit**:

This applies at least if the language used is .NET and the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the language you are willing to implement this in.

For example, in shell with `sed`:

```
$ echo '<overlay id="B66" x="600">' | sed -re 's/<overlay id="([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2})" x=\"600\"/<overlay id="\1" x="666"/'
<overlay id="B66" x="666">
```

Anyway, read the documentation on the replacement function you use in your language.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the flexibility of lookaround assertions..

search:
`'%(<overlay(?=\s)[^>]*(?<=\s)x\s*=\s*(["\']))\s*600\s*(\2[^>]*/?>)%'`

replace:
`"${1}9000${3}"`

```
expanded:
'%
  (<overlay (?=\s)[^>]* (?<=\s)x\s*=\s*(["']))
  \s*600\s*
  (\2[^>]*/?>)
%x'
```